# Is it possible for a thread to call a thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Say I have this code:

```
public int A = 0;

//This is the method that will
//be run as a thread
public void Thread1()
{
    public bool continue = true;
    while (continue == true)
    {
        if (A==2)
        {
            Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Thread2));
        }

        //Some other code here
    }

}

//This is the method that Thread1
//will try to run if A = 2
public void Thread2()
{
    //Coding in this thread
}
```

Say that the int A gets set to 2 from an other method or something similar. Would the thread1 be able to create the new thread2 from inside itself? I felt that I would ask, because I have a habit of messing up my code bigtime when I try and do something I don't fully understand.

Comment: Technically a thread can create another thread... this happens all the time... your application starts with one main thread...

Comment: if you have tested it you would have the answer

Comment: "continue" is probably not the best variable name in C# since it's also a keyword.

Comment: @Inisheer, thanks, I was using it as an example, but i'll keep that in mind for my real application. You learn something new every day!

Comment: @ApachePilotMPE I figured it was just for the example. However, I saw your comment on TGH's answer that you had just started programming so I thought I would throw that in in the event you didn't know. :)

Comment: I am not sure there is a good way to answer this question.  Your comment below would seem to indicate you are new to programming, in which my advice would be to not try to engage in any multi-threading as multi-threaded programming is very hard.  As a case in point your checking of a variable (that presumably could be changed by another thread) that is not locked is not good practice.  Instead you would use the syncronization classes such as AutoResetEvent, ManualResetEvent or Mutex.

Comment: You are confusing yourself by naming methods `Thread1` and `Thread2`. These are not threads, these are methods and they can be called from any thread or any number of threads. I think, that in your case this is an important distinction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible for threads to create other threads.
Keep in mind that the "default single thread" that your program loads up in is just another normal thread, so you're already creating a new thread from a thread when you're starting thread1

Comment: Oh OK, I'm still fairly new to things like this, I only started programming a few days ago. Thanks for the quick response!